# How to add a project to the gerrit code review tool?

Tags: git, gerrit

How do I manually add a project to the gerrit code review tool?

I've seen some examples that execute a gerrit binary but my installation doesn't appear to have one of these.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For older Gerrit versions, you need to use the ssh interface.  Set up your public key in the web interface then run:

```
ssh -p <port> <user>@<gerrit-host> gerrit --help
```

This will list you the available commands.  What you actually need to run to create your project is:

```
ssh -p <port> <user>@<gerrit-host> gerrit create-project -n <project-name>
```

In Gerrit 2.3 and newer, you may alternatively create projects from the UI, by going to Admin->Projects->Create New Project.

Comment: I've added the public key but get this error... any ideas? Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: Are you using the right username?  I forgot to put that in my answer...  I usually set up my ssh config with an alias so that I don't need to specify the port or the user

Comment: Can you please clarify what I should do after adding a public key in web UI? Cause I still get permission denied error.  sorry for so dummy question, but I stuck on that.

Answer (score 3):

From gerrit 2.3.x, if you are in Administrator, you can create the project in the web as well.

It is visible under Admin/Projects if you have permission.